# Creating panels on the fly?

Tags: java, gwt

When I'm running through the results of my sqlite query, I would like to create HorizontalPanels in my VerticalPanel and populate the panel with Labels based on the query results. How might I create these panels and labels on the fly?

I was thinking `mainPanel.add(new HorizontalPanel().add(new Label("my text")));` but that doesn't work and I have multiple labels for each panel.

Comment: Did you do a GUI refresh/repaint?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's a good way of doing the same basic task multiple times?

```
for (DataItem d:dataSet){
    HorizontalPanel p=new HorizontalPanel();
    p.add(new Label(d.getData()));
    myVerticalPanel.add(p);
}
```

Adapt that to your specific needs, using the right method calls and class names.

Comment: If I wanted to toggle the visibility of one of the labels, how would I access it?

Comment: If you've got the index of the label, you could do it like this `myVerticalPanel.get(ind).get(0).setVisible(false)`.  Failing that, when you're creating the panels, store the labels in a list, for direct access.

Comment: I can do myVerticalPanel.getWidget(2) but I can't seem to drill down any further to get the label. myVerticalPanel.get doesn't come up as an option

Comment: ((ComplexPanel) myVerticalPanel.getWidget(i)).getWidget(1).setVisible(false) seems to work.

Comment: Sorry, yeah.  Spaced on that one :)  getWidget is the appropriate method to use.